Limit and Offset are supported by Content Provider?
I want to fetch data from content with help of Paging but limit and offset are not working
      val sortOrder = "${MediaStore.Images.Media._ID} DESC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset"

       contentResolver.query(collectionUri ,projection,
            null , null,
           sortOrder

        )


LIMIT and OFFSET are features of the SQL SELECT query syntax. There is no requirement for a ContentProvider to be backed by a SQL database, and there is no requirement for the ContentProvider to support all features of a SQL SELECT statement.
Whether LIMIT and OFFSET will work depends on the specific ContentProvider implementation. In your case, you appear to be querying MediaStore. If so, the implementation of MediaStore can vary by OS version and by device model (if manufacturers make changes to it).
Personally, I would not rely on LIMIT and/or OFFSET to be available on MediaStore.

How you manage 25k images from content provider without  limit and offset?

@AhsanAli: Personally, I have not had to worry about this concern. You might look into open source apps that use MediaStore and see how they approach the problem.
